# WebView is Not Working for Second Time in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App is crashed when i navigate to webview page for second time. I used try catch blocks for every event but app is crashed with out throwing any Exception. I Dot not know what is happening, Please help me to rectify this...

XAML Code:

```
  <WebView  VerticalAlignment="Top"                  
              Loaded="WBrowser_Loaded"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             NavigationFailed="WBrowser_NavigationFailed" 
             Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="WBrowser"
             ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Height="570" 
             Grid.Row="0"  Width="370"></WebView>
```

Cs Code:

```
 private void WBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  try
   {
    WBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
   }
  catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }
 }

private void WBrowser_NavigationFailed(object sender, WebViewNavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
       // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
       System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your webview get loaded twice? I see once when navigating to the phone page, what about the second time? Can you show us more code?

Comment: it means when Navigating to webview page for second time

Comment: I checked your code and its working fine. On click button event of a page I am navigating to new page with your webview and on back button press navigating back then repeated the same steps  again but still no crash

Comment: Then why i have face this problem..

Comment: most probably its some other code thats causing this issue. Can you also test if you are able to open any webpage through internet explorer in your device/emulator? Might be that issue that you are facing.